# How to get enum when you only got a unique subfield of that enum

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, enums

The purpose of this enum is to convert incoming api_errors to their corresponding enum, so that my Notifier component know what they have to display solely by the error-msg received from the server.

Say I receive the error-msg "Incorrect password or username", how do I convert that into the corresponding enum `NotifyEnum.ERR_INCORRECT_PWD_OR_USERNAME`?

```
 export const NotifyEnum = Object.freeze({
        ERR_INCORRECT_PWD_OR_USERNAME: {
            type: NotifyTypeEnum.ERROR,
            msg: "Incorrect password or username"
        },
        ERR_USERNAME_IS_ALREADY_TAKEN: {
            type: NotifyTypeEnum.ERROR,
            msg: "Username is already registered"
        },
        ERR_EMAIL_IS_ALREADY_IN_USE: {
            type: NotifyTypeEnum.ERROR,
            msg: "Email is already in use"
        },
        NOTICE_PWDS_DO_NOT_MATCH: {
            type: NotifyTypeEnum.NOTICE,
            msg: "Passwords do not match"
        }
    })
```

---

```
export const NotifyTypeEnum = Object.freeze({
    ERROR: {
        title: "Error",
        duration: 5000
    },
    NOTICE: {
        title: "Notice",
        duration: 2000
    }
})
```

... perhaps I should structure my Enum in another way?

Comment: Why does your server send back an error message instead of the enum code in the first place?

Comment: @Bergi Oh well, guess because I didn't think of that. Now that you mention it, it does sound a lot smarter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with this, something like this is the only way:

```
const NotifyTypeEnum = Object.freeze({
  ERROR: {
    title: "Error",
    duration: 5000
  },
  NOTICE: {
    title: "Notice",
    duration: 2000
  }
})

const NotifyEnum = Object.freeze({
  ERR_INCORRECT_PWD_OR_USERNAME: {
    type: NotifyTypeEnum.ERROR,
    msg: "Incorrect password or username"
  },
  ERR_USERNAME_IS_ALREADY_TAKEN: {
    type: NotifyTypeEnum.ERROR,
    msg: "Username is already registered"
  },
  ERR_EMAIL_IS_ALREADY_IN_USE: {
    type: NotifyTypeEnum.ERROR,
    msg: "Email is already in use"
  },
  NOTICE_PWDS_DO_NOT_MATCH: {
    type: NotifyTypeEnum.NOTICE,
    msg: "Passwords do not match"
  }
})



const message = "Incorrect password or username";

const key = Object.keys(NotifyEnum).find(k => NotifyEnum[k].msg === message);

console.log(key);
```